# PROCEDURE can't return a result set in the given context

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails(3.2.1, mysql2) app, i want to call and show results from a procedure 
I google and tried diff ways, but no luck, issue is still the same here is code snipet i am using to call the procedure

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("call sp_name(1,10)")
```

below is the error i get on executing this code

```
Mysql2::Error: PROCEDURE sp_name can't return a result set in the given      
context: call sp_name(1, 10)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: PROCEDURE sp_name can't    
return a result set in the given context: call user_childs(1, 10)
from /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-  
3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:233:in `query'
from /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@sharetok/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:233:in `block in execute'
from /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
from /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
from /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
from /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:233:in `execute'
from /home/ankit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:214:in `execute'
```

Comment: I believe it's more about mysql than rails. You should add appropriate tag and provide procedure code so mysql experts could answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem with Rails, see this [blog post](http://spectator.in/2011/03/12/rails2-mysql2-and-stored-procedures/) for more details.

I personally use the code from the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/1367987) in some of my applications.

If you want to use multiple result sets in your rails code, you can use my fork of the [mysql2 gem](https://github.com/wok/mysql2)

Comment: Yes that post helped me out. Rails latest version must have it by default, not sure why rails team wants to avoid the procedure use? may be its not the rails way, but procedures are life savers in many situations. Anyway thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I guess the rails philosophy is to be database agnostic, and since stored procedures are not available everywhere they do not need to be supported by Rails